# String literal with line breaks in Tcl

Tags: tcl, expect

I want to have a string in my source code that consists of multiple lines (i.e contains LF characters).

The solution should:

1. Put each data line on a separate source line.

   ```
   # Bad:
   set lines "line 1\nline 2\nline 3"
   ```
2. Not add empty leading or trailing lines:

   ```
   # Bad:
   set lines {
   line 1
   line 2
   line 3
   }
   puts [split $lines \n]
   # Prints: {} {line 1} {line 2} {line 3} {}
   ```
3. Not have hanging lines:

   ```
   # Bad:
   set lines {line 1
   line 2
   line 3}
   ```

What I have came up with so far:

```
set lines {
line 1
line 2
line 3
}
set lines [string range $lines 1 end-1]
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: I'd use `string trim` instead of `string range`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

```
% set lines [join [list {*}{
   "line 1"
   "line 2"
   "line 3"
}] \n]
% split $lines \n
{line 1} {line 2} {line 3}
```

Comment: I see what you did there. A bit too much syntactic noise for my taste. Having to quote each line is especially awkward.

Comment: Don't list and {*} cancel each other out?

Comment: They do, but you win the freedom to arrange the strings/ lines within {*}{...} as you please. Besides, as for syntactic noise, you were specific about everything but quoting ;) That said, quotes will give you some syntax highlighting in some environments. Overall, a cosmetic thing.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going with option 2 and removing the empty lines at the beginning and end via [string trim](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/string.html#M45)

```
set lines {
line 1
line 2
line 3
}
set lines [string trim $lines]
puts [split $lines \n]
```

Prints:

```
{line 1} {line 2} {line 3}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/OLVEISczL7VYoZoLRCsYQigjCGXMVcuFUBJdXFKUmZeuACRzFVTAYrFcBaUlIJmCnMwSqJhCTF7s//8A)